# Is there a way to provision aws sso users via cloudformation/cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sso

Looking at this guide:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/use-new-account-assignment-apis-for-aws-sso-to-automate-multi-account-access/

It only shows how to assign permission sets to already existing users. Also looking at the cloudformation documentation, it does not mention anything about users.

Is there a way to create aws sso users via cloudformation or cdk?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why this is not yet supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly this is **not  yet supported**. [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/IdentityStoreAPIReference/welcome.html) say that in future such support should be added, at least to AWS API, which then you could use from custom resources in CloudFormation:

> **Future** updates to AWS SSO Identity Store APIs, including additions for **creation and modification of users and groups**, will be documented in this reference as they are released.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Infrastructure as Code you can use Terraform and Boto3 to create SSO users.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/identitystore_user

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/identitystore.html#client

Answer (score 0):

Just posted an example project in CDK Python adapted from a recent client project, here:
https://github.com/matwerber1/aws-cdk-sso-user-management

The project contains a custom CDK resource backed by Lambda that uses the IAM identitystore `create_user`, `update_user`, and `delete_user` APIs to manage SSO users, as well as wrappers around the L1 constructs like `CfnGroup`, `CfnGroupMembership`, and so on to make it easier to add users in bulk to a group, or assign groups+permission sets to accounts.

If you use Typescript, it could be converted pretty easily, I think.

Feedback and PRs welcome, as I'm sure there's room for improvement.

Example usage below:

```py
class SsoStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        user_foo = SsoUser(
            self,
            user_attributes=SsoUserAttributes(
                email="someuser1@",
                username="username",
                first_name="Foo",
                last_name="Foo",
            ),
        )
        user_bar = SsoUser(
            self,
            user_attributes=SsoUserAttributes(
                email="someuser2@",
                username="username2",
                first_name="Bar",
                last_name="Bar",
            ),
        )

        all_users = [user_foo, user_bar]

        # Reference existing perission sets
        SsoPermissionSet.from_existing_permission_set(
            self,
            permission_set_name="AWSOrganizationsFullAccess",
            permission_set_arn=f"{SsoConfig.instance_arn.value}/ps-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        )

        # Create new permission sets
        demo_permission_set = SsoPermissionSet(
            self,
            name="DemoPermissionSet",
            description="demo permission set",
            inline_policy=iam.PolicyDocument(
                statements=[
                    iam.PolicyStatement(
                        effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                        actions=["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"],
                        resources=["*"],
                    )
                ]
            ).to_string()
        )

        # Create new groups
        demo_group = SsoGroup(
            self,
            group_name="Demo User Group",
            description="Admin and read-only role to sandbox account",
        )

        # add user(s) to a group
        demo_group.add_users(all_users)

        # add permission set to a group for a given account
        demo_permission_set.grant_to_group_for_account(demo_group, AwsAccounts.SANDBOX.value)
```