# AWS SSO: Assign existing users to specific accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-cdk

I use IAM identity center(SSO previously) to manage users and accounts.

I made a typescript CDK application that creates AWS accounts under a specific Organisational Unit.

Now I need to to assign users to the created accounts so they can login to them. It has to be automated but I can't find a CDK construct or cli commands for that.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: There are no hand-written (L2) constructs for this service yet. However, you can still use the automatically generated L1 constructs, and use this service exactly as you would using CloudFormation directly. Use the automatically generated L1 constructs, in the same way you would use the [CloudFormation AWS::SSO resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_SSO.html) directly.

Answer (score 0):

I made a CDK construct that does exactly this... allows you to create, update, or delete new SSO users as well as "import" existing users to a CDK project as an `SsoUser` object. It's in Python but could easily be ported to to Typescript CDK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77356500/6715798